# ng build failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL cannot be created in a document with origin 'null' and URL

Tags: angular, angular-router, ng-build

I am using Google Chrome version 52 and I want to be able to run my application locally without a server by accessing index.html.

I am able to hit the landing page of my application. However, when I try to navigate to another page or click on any buttons, it is unable to work.

I have tried many ways, such as:

- Add script before import [reference one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32481260/failed-to-execute-replacestate-on-history-local-url-cannot-be-created-in-a) and [reference two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32453806/uncaught-securityerror-failed-to-execute-replacestate-on-history-cannot-be)
- Changing base href from / to ./
- Changing router configurations to use hash and changing base href to 
  `<script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>`
- Using `ng build --prod --allow-file-access-from-files`

This is the exact error I faced:
[image]

I have been trying for a day, would really appreciate if someone could help.

I do not wish to run a web server and I have to make it work on Chrome.

Edited:
Works on Safari

Does not work on Chrome, Firefox, Opera, IE, Microsoft Edge

Thank you!

Comment: do you use the angular router? are you able to access the root of `yourdomain.com/`, if you refresh your page?

Comment: @JiiB Hi, yes I use angular router for navigation. After refresh, I am on my root page.

Comment: Does the navigation work, if you use `ng serve` or do you have the same problem, like in the bundled version?

Comment: @JiiB yes the navigation works for ng serve, no errors observed

Answer (score 0):

There a a few reasons, that could cause problems with your router. If you experience problems in your production environment, you should make sure, that you follow these steps:

#### Step 1:

Add a base tag in the header section of your index.html:

```
<base href="/">
```

#### Step 2:

Createa `.htaccess` file in your root directory and set the `ErrorDocument` on your index.html, like in the example below.

```
RewriteEngine On

ErrorDocument 404 /
```

This should fix your issues.

#### Explanation:

When you load a page, e. g. domain.com/settings, your browser sends a request to the server and expects a settings.html file in response.

If the ErrorDocument points to the index.html file, the Angular router can handle the request correctly and will redirect you to domain.com/settings without getting a error.

Comment: I have tried according to what you said and place the .htaccess file in my dist folder, does not work. The error is exactly the same as the screenshot I provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up I use [Web Server for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en) to host a simple local server, which was not what I wanted but it's better than nothing.

Still hoping if anyone could solve this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use hash location strategy and remove the base tag in index.html entirely.